# Find duplicate value in excel using c# with epplus library

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I want to check whether there are any duplicate rows present in an excel file using c# code. 
Is there any code snippet which can help me to find duplicate rows using c# ?

Note : Use of EPPlus for excel interaction is preferable.

Comment: why use EPPlus or even why use C#, not excel formulas or vba?

Comment: Do you want to search the whole excel file for cells with the same value? Try to be some more specific.

Comment: @LeiYang, i have excel files on a server where ms office is not installed so i can not use vba there. i am creating a utility for automation that needs to check duplicate data in whole excel file using c#. that's why epplus is needed.

Comment: @Sammy, i want to check that one whole row is not getting repeated in the whole excel sheet. Suppose, i have a sheet with 5 column and 3 rows. so, i want to check that whether row[1] = '{ cell[1,1],cell[1,2] ..}' is equal to row[2] .

Comment: What about simple ado.net, read all data in memory then compare?

Comment: @LeiYang, can you provide some sample code for that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [msdn](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306572/how-to-query-and-display-excel-data-by-using-asp.net,-ado.net,-and-visual-c-.net)

Answer (score 0):

Even with this less information, try if that does what you want:

```
public static bool HasDuplicates(string path)
{
    List<object> allObjects = new List<object>();

    using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(path)))
    {
        // Go through all sheets
        foreach (var sheet in excel.Workbook.Worksheets)
        {
            // Go through all cells
            foreach (var cell in sheet.Cells)
            {
                // Ignore null cells
                if(cell.Value != null)
                {
                    if (allObjects.Contains(cell.Value))
                        return true;
                    allObjects.Add(cell.Value);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

PS: This code is not tested

Comment: Every time it returns true. 
`ID Name State ||
1 Abc Pune || 
1 Abc Gujarat ||  
3 Xyz Delhi` 
This should not give me true as first row is not exact similar to row 2.